# Create checkbox-frame and wait for selection

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I'm trying to create a little popup-menu that displays a series of checkboxes to the user in Java. After making a selection the user presses a button and the selection should be passed to my main program.

Currently I have a class SelectionFrame that extends JFrame. What would be the best way to do the following things

- Let the main program wait until the button in the SelectionFrame is pressed
- At that point, make the SelectionFrame send the selection to the main program

I have tried to do this by settings a boolean in the SelectionFrame that turns true when the button is pressed. I let the main program wait until the value of this boolean is true and then retrieve the selection from the SelectionFrame. For some reason this does not work.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I clearly stated in my question the two things which I would like to have advice on. 1) How to make the main program wait until the button in the frame is pressed and 2) how to make the frame send back the value to the main program

Comment: I'm not asking you to fix my code, I'm asking for advice.

Comment: Please do not reply if you do not intend to help. If _What would be the best way to do the following things_ is not nice enough for you (including: _Thanks for the advice!_) then don't bother

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a window that opens and allows the user to interact only with that window until it is closed you need a modal dialog box, not a frame. This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) explains how to make dialogs. You can simply setModal() to true. That would mean that the calling method would wait until the dialog s closed.

Comment: Additionally, look into how to make a thread wait until the dialog's button is pressed.